# How to attach the file in Chrome using Selenium RC?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

**HTML CODE:**

```
<tr>
<td>
Filename:
<br>
<input type="file" size="35" name="filename">
<input type="hidden" value="Hidden Field Value" name="hiddenField">
</td>
</tr>
```

In Chrome this field looks as a button with label as choosefile. I am trying to click that button to attach file, but i could not able to. Trying to use the attachfile command as well.

No luck. Can any one let me know how to resolve this?

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has inbuilt security restrictions which doesnt allows you to specify the uploaded file via javascripts. So sadly, there is no workaround for this issue.